# Minimal Salesforce License to use LMA and Subscriber Support

Tags: isv, subscriber, lma, lmo

I couldn't find any information on what's the minimum Salesforce license to grant a support person permissions to do Subscriber Support in the LMA.

Can someone please point me to such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a dance with Salesforce support they confirmed that in Salesforce there is no single document stating what is needed for that but here it is:

**You need:**

1. `Sales Cloud Standard User` License, Sys Admin not needed
2. Read Access to `Leads`, View All is not required
3. `Log in to Subscriber Organization` system permission (a permission set is enough for that)
4. Access to the LMA visualforce pages: `sfLma.SubscriberSupport` and `sfLma.LoginToPartnerBT`

Comment: Thanks for this info, can confirm it worked. Strange Salesforce contradicts this (and doesn't define what they mean by admin): https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KPIhQAO&title=logging-in-to-subscriber-orgs-as-a-non-admin-user-from-licenses-page-fails-with-noaccessexception

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an explicit document that states this for sure, but checking a few different type of profiles based on license types, it appears that the Log in to Subscriber Org permission can only be set on Salesforce licenses. I don't have access to the more esoteric licenses, so I can't confirm all of the license types, but it seems that you need to use a license that has at least core CRM functionality (Leads, Accounts, and Contacts). Chatter, Community, and Portal users don't have the necessary core features to use LMA.